# Create REST API in codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I need to create a RESTful web api using only CodeIgniter. I need your help you can give me any links tutorials or any other helpong material. I have seen that most of the people are using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver i have also did that but when i open the file there are errors in it. I am using dream weaver. Kindly provide me with  helping material you can

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Follow https://www.formget.com/php-rest-api/

Comment: @AmanKumar i have followed it and i have errors in formget code such as authentication error  variable not declared etc

Comment: Please share your errors, I have used same rest server and Its working perfect.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya these errors im facing while use formget turotial
 " <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message: Undefined index: hash</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1866</p> "
</div>not authorized{"status":false,"error":"Not authorized"}

Answer (score 0):

If you have used

`$config['rest_enable_keys'] = TRUE;`

in your `config/rest.php` file then make it FALSE

`$config['rest_enable_keys'] = FALSE;`.

Because it seems like you have issue with keys.

> Key Table

```
CREATE TABLE `keys` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `level` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `ignore_limits` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_created` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you please check your error log and share it here.

Comment: after Making it TRUE i'm receiving this error
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
<p>Error Number: 1146</p><p>Table 'api.keys' doesn't exist</p><p>SELECT *
FROM `keys`
WHERE `key` = 'REST API'</p><p>Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/MB/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php</p><p>Line Number: 963</p> </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It means it required key table., Please check my answer and create key table.

Comment: thankyou very much sir for your help!! really it means alot but now after making that keys table it is again giving me this error " </div>not authorized{"status":false,"error":"Not authorized"} "  and also this one
" <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message: Undefined index: hash</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1866</p> " 
i have changed the $config['rest_enable_keys'] = TRUE;
form TRUE to FALSE but error is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147222/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-dawood-basharat).

Comment: Click on this link and enter in chat, Lets solve this issue, : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147222/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-dawood-basharat